# How can I format the date in Meteor?

Tags: datetime, meteor

I have a date document it format so DD.MM.YY hh:mm, I need to find today's record but i shouldnt use to hh:mm .how can I do this

```
Template.bugunIadeList.helpers({
  bugunIadeList: function(){
    var date = new Date()
    var bugun = moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY");

    return Rezervasyon.find({todaydate:bugun });

  }
});
```

> todaydate:08.08.2015 11.18
>     bugun:08.08.2015
>   so They cant be equal. I must format "todaydate" like "bugun"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one, I Think the problem is not date format. If you try to find reservation by using date range you can get the todays reservation list.

```
 var today = new Date();
 var tomorrow = new Date(today);
 tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

 return Rezervasyon.find(
 {
     todaydate: {$gte: today , $lt: tomorrow }
 });
```